# ReactJs app crashes with error "Consider adding error boundaries to your tree"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to build a random quote API app with React. When first time app loads on button click it generates the random quote, but on the second click the app crashes with

> Error occured in App Component
>
> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    quotes: null
  };
  componentDidMount() {
  fetch("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        // console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          quotes: data.quotes
        });
      });
    // console.log(this.state.quotes);
  }
  randomQuoteHandler = () => {
    const randNumb = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.quotes.length);
    const randomQuote = this.state.quotes[randNumb];
    this.setState({
      quotes: randomQuote
    });
    console.log(this.state.quotes);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.randomQuoteHandler}>gen</button>
        <p>{this.state.quotes !== null && this.state.quotes.quote}</p>
        <p> {this.state.quotes !== null && this.state.quotes.author}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you add full trace of error message ? In which format does your data comes ? Array of objects might be the correct guess. So if it's array then it's object type behaviour causes error in JSX hence causing error in render method

Comment: @MeetZaveri you can check the codesandbox here https://codesandbox.io/s/6xl28oq2nr 
P.S on second click error is generated!

Answer (score 5):

The `randomQuoteHandler` replaces `this.state.quotes` array with a chosen `quote` which is an object. So on the second click, `this.state.quotes.length` is undefined.

You need to store the chosen quote in another state variable like `randomQuote`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    quotes: null,
    randomQuote: null,
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(
      'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/camperbot/5a022b72e96c4c9585c32bf6a75f62d9/raw/e3c6895ce42069f0ee7e991229064f167fe8ccdc/quotes.json',
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        // console.log(data);
        this.setState({
          quotes: data.quotes,
        })
      })
    // console.log(this.state.quotes);
  }
  randomQuoteHandler = () => {
    const randNumb = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.quotes.length)
    const randomQuote = this.state.quotes[randNumb]
    this.setState({
      randomQuote: randomQuote,
    })
    console.log(this.state.quotes)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.randomQuoteHandler}>gen</button>
        <p>{this.state.randomQuote !== null && this.state.randomQuote.quote}</p>
        <p>{this.state.randomQuote !== null && this.state.randomQuote.author}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeh that makes a perfect sense thanks for the help!

Comment: @james you're welcome sir. please consider marking it as answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the `randomQuoteHandler`  you are replacing the whole array of `quotes` with the random `randomQuote` object. The `log` at the end of this `randomQuoteHandler` function is showing that.

```
this.setState({
  quotes: randomQuote  // Array get replaced by one object
});
```

therefore the second time there is no array in the sate to read `this.state.quotes.quote`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my own application. Basically this error occurred because my application was trying to read an object that was in the wrong format.

In my case I was accidentally using `JSON.stringify()` **twice** before storing to `localStorage`, and so when my application went to read this data from `localStorage` it was in an unexpected format.

In general if you get this error in your application, make sure that you're storing objects in the intended format so they can be read properly.